# Trigger error: We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

My Gapps script called from time based trigger is logging tons of errors "We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED".
I assume there are users, who installed the app and trigger, but later removed permissions for script to run. Which, obviously, may cause this issue.
I'm still trying and failing to avoid it...

This is how trigger is installed:

```
var triggerFunction = "processRecurrentLists";  //trigger callback function name

//---------------------------------------------
function createTriggers(tmz) {
  // Trigger running at 1am depending on timezone specified in settings
  // If no timezone specified, script timezone is used (GMT)
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunction)
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .inTimezone(tmz)
      .atHour(1)
      .create();
      
}
```

This is the triggered function:

```
function processRecurrentLists() {
  // Check if the actions of the trigger requires authorization that has not
  // been granted yet; if not, then end - nothing to do.
  if (!isScriptAuthorized()) {
    console.warn("RecGTasks script is not authorized to run. Please, authorize first.");
    return;
  }

  // ... more code here
}
```

And function testing authorization:

```
function isScriptAuthorized() {
  try {
    var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
    return (authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() == ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.NOT_REQUIRED);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn("Script not authorized. err=%s",e.message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

My assumption is that function *isScriptAuthorized* returns false if script is not authorized and script ends gracefully, but it seems not to be the case...

Any idea on this?

**Update 1**
I have made script accessible for all users as a workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175139769 and on the same day message changed to "Authorization is required to perform that action.", so no more PERMISSION_DENIED. Investigating further.

**Update 2**
Yes, as @ziganotschka pointed out, it is related to V8. I used following script to test it thoroughly:

```
function doGet() {
  // if trigger not installed
  if (ScriptApp
      .getProjectTriggers()
      .filter(function(t){return t.getHandlerFunction() === "myFunction"})
      .length == 0
     ){
    // create trigger firing every 1min
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();      
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Trigger test installed</h1>');
}

function myFunction() { 
  Logger.log("Hello from triggered function");
  return ("Hello from server");
}
```

Comment: Related [Container-bound Script getting permission errors trying to run functions with google.script.run from sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60442915/1595451), [Web App call fails with “… Error code INTERNAL” with Custom API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61967246/1595451)

Comment: Do you use propertiesService? Are you sure you are not using any client side features- sidebar, modal dialogs?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, propertiesService. And yes, I'm sure no client side features are used. That script is "recalculating" tasks, so basically it only reads tasks, and writes them back.

Comment: Maybe related to [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152070295). The links pointing to @google/clasp suggests creating a new version manually as a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It seems to be a bug related to the v8 runtime

Have a look [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/149114362) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/149423390).

This problem seems to occur when users are signed in with multiple accounts at once.

While Google is fixing the bug, I suggest you to temprorily disable the v8 runtime to avoid the problem.

Comment: Bugs you are referring to are UI add-on related and relevant for browser/frontend environment. My case is more backend related - does not relate to browser & multiple accounts. I will anyway try using previous version of engine. Will let you know.

Comment: It is true that the users who filed those bugs were using the UI, but it does not necessary mean that the bug occurs only those conditions. So you best bet is to test either disabling v8 will also solve the issue in your case.

Comment: Tried going back to older runtime. So far it does not help.

Comment: I am sorry that my answer did not solve your issue. What is the rest of your code doing? I assume you are deplloying an Add-on?

Comment: No, it's being deployed as web-app and the purpose was to implement recurring tasks for Google Calendar, back in 2015. Whole code is here if you are interested https://github.com/jsdev2015/recgtasks @ziganotschka

Comment: The whole code is certainly a bit long to reproduce, however with the short version I cannot reproduce your error - if the user revokes the scopes, it would also revoke `Allow this application to run when you are not present`, which would mean that the trigger would be deactivated, and thus - `processRecurrentLists() `would not run and could not lead to an eeror.

Comment: I have even tried to enclose whole code into one big try-catch statement - hoping to catch that error, but no change.

Comment: So, thoroughly tested and... it is related to V8.