# Google Apps Script deployed (add-on) - a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I have a Google Apps Script sheets add-on project that is deployed to Google Cloud Platform.

The app has an Add-ons menu and a number of buttons with assigned scripts.

Locally (code running in the script editor), the menu items and buttons run the assigned scripts correctly.

When the project is deployed to GCP, the menu items run correctly,
but clicking a button does not run the assigned function.

This is displayed `Running script Cancel Dismiss` but the assigned function does not run

The following error is logged to GCP logging:
"We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED."

What permission is required to run an assigned script from a button in an add-on?

appsscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ]
}
```

```
export function fncTest() {
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124449/trigger-error-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage

Comment: Does it occurr if you run with the rhino runtime? You'll have to drop the export keyword to test, however