# Unsuccessfull runs for time-based trigger action on other accounts, but works fine on mine

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, triggers

I have a Google Apps Script that works perfectly on my account. I've deployed that script as a web app and shared it with my friend, sadly each time the time-based function should be called I see errors for his account.

My test script is very simple (based on [Trigger error: We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124449/trigger-error-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage)):

```
function doGet() {

  const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()

  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    const handlerFunction = triggers[i].getHandlerFunction();
    if (handlerFunction === 'myFunction') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i])
    }
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Trigger test installed</h1>');
}

function myFunction() {
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log("Hello "+ email);
}
```

My project runs on V8 and I have this `appsscript.json`:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Warsaw",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the issue from a [2 years old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124449/trigger-error-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage) is still there, but my case is a bit different, because as I wrote on start, this works perfectly on my account, but not on others account.

In the linked question the answer suggests disabling the V8, but this way I'm unable to debug my code (I'm using the web editor), so it will be a pain to develop the script.

My question is: How to fix this error using V8 runtime and sharing the web app (published Apps Script) with others

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. In Chrome open https://script.google.com/home
2. Create a new project, and call it "Bug Report"
3. Paste the above code in the editor and save the changes:
   [image]
4. Click on deploy > new deploy and pick web app as the type. Specify Execute as to user opening the website and allow access to anyone having a google account:
   [image]
5. Hit deploy and copy the generated link
6. Access the link in the new tab (still logged in to google), view permissions, and finally, you will get the "Trigger test installed" sign.
7. Return to your Apps Script project and go to logs, you will see info that myFunction was successfully executed:
   [image]
8. Open a different browser (Edge in my case), log in to a different google account, and open the same link you got in step 4. View and accept permissions.
9. You will get the same message ("Trigger test installed")
10. Return to Chrome, to logs and you will get the error messages:
    [image]

Comment: When I tested your script by using the same with your `appsscript.json`, no error occurs on another user. `myFunction()` works fine by the installed time-driven trigger. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, about `shared it with my friend`, in this case, your Google Apps Script project is shared with the user as the writer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I've added step-by-step instructions on how to recreate the error I'm having. I'm not sure if this is because I'm testing the script on 2 google accounts on the same PC, or maybe because of V8 bug or because of my mistake. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your flow, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In your flow, at section 8, you use `Open a different browser (Edge in my case)`. But, at section 10, you say `Return to Chrome`. I cannot understand this. In this case, Whose is `Chrome` of `Return to Chrome`? And, when you open the script editor of `Edge in my case` and confirm the log, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike as the Script owner (the author) I'm using Chrome to develop and deploy the script. I also view the logs there (on https://script.google.com/home). I use Edge where I'm logged in with a second google account to test my script (I only access the web app URL, not the script editor).
The idea is to develop on Chrome and simulate the second user on Edge. I hope this will make it more clear now :)
I can share the script id or even share the project with you if that would help to debug the error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply to my comment.

Comment: @Tanaike my last comment?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `my last comment?`, I posted my previous comment again. When I tested your flow, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In your flow, at section 8, you use `Open a different browser (Edge in my case)`. But, at section 10, you say `Return to Chrome`. I cannot understand this. In this case, Whose is `Chrome` of `Return to Chrome`? And, when you open the script editor of Edge in my case and confirm the log, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250345/discussion-between-misiu-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Tanaike I'm also not a native English speaker. I've described the details in the chat, Could you join? It will be easier to discuss there.

Comment: @Tanaike I get the same error. It looks like the time-based trigger isn't running in the context of the user who opened the app
this might be the reason for the PERMISSION_DENIED error

Comment: @Tanaike can you create a script that is using my code and share a link to the web app (deployed web application)? Maybe if I access it then you will see the error in logs.

Comment: @Tanaike look at my reported issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262140639. I must share the project with the people that will use it, so that the installable triggers will work. Ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en

Comment: @Tanaike is there an option to hide the source? At least some part of it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. But, I would like to try to replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the reason for the issue. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill. I have to study more.